# How do I code outside the console?

Tags: c#, console

I'm trying to learn c#, and what I'm using like most beginner books teach me to program using the console. My friend who uses c# tells me to learn to code not using the console but won't help me with how to do that. So how do I code outside the console? And any recommendations on how I should learn this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with learning using the console. I would take the book's advice over your friend's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a winform app from template, file->new->windows forms application.
Simply add a button and write code to the click event.
But as said, nothing wrong with console programming.